# jquery file input value to show full path or display image preview

Tags: jquery

I want the user to prepare his ad, then when they click on preview, to see all the ad info including the selected image. That way it gives them a sense of what the ad will look like before posting it.

I read that using `var img = $('input[type=file]').val();` gives a fake path and thus not displaying the image in the preview area as it doesn't know where c:/fakepath/img.jpg is.

Is there anything I can do to get the image selection to preview in the preview area (which is loaded when the preview button is clicked).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Comment: I am not trying to preview it next to the input button. I want to preview it on a page that replaces the form with a preview state and then show the image there